# What is the name of this yellow flower?

Tags: species-identification

India, It was growing outside.

April 2017

[image]

Center part of the flower giving me Heebie-jeebies.

Comment: 'Center part of the flower giving me Heebie-jeebies'... it is a compositae (= [asteraceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteraceae)) member, and  anatomically not a flower-rather an entire inflorescence . The flowers at  central part is called disk-florets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is *[Cosmos sulphureus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_sulphureus)* which is also known as yellow cosmos or sulfur cosmos. See the image (from [here](https://anjanadesigns.blogspot.com/2015/07/flowering-plants-of-kerala-yellow-cosmos.html)) as comparision:

[image]

More information can be found [here](https://anjanadesigns.blogspot.com/2015/07/flowering-plants-of-kerala-yellow-cosmos.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_sulphureus).